# alternative for waitForPageToLoad in Selenium

Tags: time, event-handling, selenium

I have a series of links on a page that take different times to load...  I want to capture the amount of time each takes... The problem I am having is that the waitForPageToLoad time if exceeded causes the test to fail and the rest of my links do not get tested... I know I could just skip suspected links in the test or set the time limit way beyond expectation, but I was hoping there was an alternative to the waitForPageToLoad that could be used to trap when a page is loaded in Selenium, so that if a page takes longer than a minute to load it doesn't end the script.

Answer (score 3):

Wawa's answer worked great for me, I just had to add the increment to the second var.

I also only wanted to wait 5 seconds, so I changed the break criteria.

```
int second = 0;
while(!selenium.IsElementPresent(mylink))
{
    if(second >= 5) 
        break;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    second++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would use:

```
int second = 0;
while(!selenium.IsElementPresent(mylink))
{
    if(second >= 300) 
        break;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

You really don't need\want the try-catch (exception) block since IsElementPresent is not supposed to throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like i might have to go to an export to perl or java to get the functionality i'm looking for then. But, the waitForElementPresent did help a lot. thanks :-)

something like...

```
    for (int second = 0; ; second++) {
        if (second >= 300) break;
        try {if (selenium.isElementPresent( mylink )) break;} 
        catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: if you can export then its always worth it. From Selenium Core/IDE there is a setTimeout call that will set the timeout for that test case to a value and if something appears before that then it will carry on

Answer (score 0):

The best way that you can do this is to set the timeout to a number far in the future because 30 seconds is the default timeout for selenium.

```
setTimout | 300
```

And then you can do `waitForElementPresent` call on an object on the next page if you don't want to do `waitForPageToLoad`

Comment: waitForElementPresent gets me close, but I also need the timeout to end the test for the link if it takes like 5mins and I need it to continue the script and test the rest of the links etc..

Comment: you are always going to have to use setTimeout with a value far in the future then