# Selenium waitforpopup

Tags: selenium, popup, automated-tests

How to stop the selenium server until a popup opens?

We have `selenium.waitForPageToLoad` to stop the server until the Page Loads. But is there any way to stop it for Popup?

I tried it with `selenium.WaitForPopup`, but I can't find popup id. Because I created a popup box with div element(whose id is popup_container).

And I tried the following code:

```
selenium.WaitForPopUp("id=popup_container", "30000");
```

But that doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: To clarify, the popup is a div tag like seen in this [demo](http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'popup' is not actually a popup, it's just a div tag. So you want to wait until that element (div tag) is present. There is a method to check if the element is present:

```
selenium.IsElementPresent(div_of_the_popup)
```

You can loop checking until the element is present or a certain time expires. You can see sample loops at this other [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1202218/alternative-for-waitforpagetoload-in-selenium).

The later versions of Selenium, do include methods for doing the wait for element. Ultimately, the key to your problem is waiting for the DIV not a popup.

**UPDATE**: Based on your other posts, it looks like you are using Selenium-Webdriver. If so, then you can use the example from the selenium web page for [explicit waits](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html)

Answer (score 0):

**C#**

Your popup is actually a div. You can do it like this:

```
Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.Id("Popup_Div_Id")));
```